# Hide elements nested more than twice in recursive tree

Tags: javascript

I have the following structure:

```
var structure = {
  name: 'root',
  type: 'folder',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'aaa',
      type: 'leaf'
    },
    {
      name: 'bbb',
      type: 'leaf'
    },
    {
      name: 'folder2',
      type: 'folder',
      children: [...]
    } 
  ]
};
```

that I use to create something like a file system:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="folder">
      <td>folder</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="children">
      <tr>
        <td>Child1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Child2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="folder">
        <td>Folder 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="children">
        <td>Child 3...</td>
      </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So a folder contains two `tr`'s - one with its name, one with children.
Children can be leafs without folders, or folders themselves.

This is the code converting structure to html:

```
var convert = function (data) {
    var elements = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i in data) {
            var element = createTr();
            if (data[i].type == undefined) { // if is leaf
              element.appendChild('some leaf text node');
            } else if (data[i].type === "folder") {
                element.appendChild('some folder text node');
            }
            elements.appendChild(element);
            if (data[i].type === "folder") {
                var element = createTr(convert(data[i].children));
                elements.appendChild(element);
            }
        }
        return elements;
    };
```

---

How do I append `display: none` in this function when the nesting level is higher than 2? How do I get nesting level in this function?

I tried passing a variable in recursive call, but then the variable gets incremented each time there's a new folder, not a new nesting level.

How should I do this?

EDIT: That's how I tried to fix this:

```
var convert = function (data, level) {
        level = level || 0;
        var elements = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (var i in data) {
                var element = createTr();
                if (data[i].type == undefined) { // if is leaf
                  element.appendChild('some leaf text node');
                } else if (data[i].type === "folder") {
                    element.appendChild('some folder text node');
                }
                elements.appendChild(element);
                if (data[i].type === "folder") {
                    var element = createTr(convert(data[i].children, ++level));
                    elements.appendChild(element);
                }
            }
            return elements;
        };
```

Comment: Sure! I edited my post. The thing is that level variables increments each time on new folder, not on new nesting.

Comment: there's a difference between your edit, and my proposal: `++level` increments the variable in the current scope, whereas passing in `level + 1` does not.  (That's why, in the code I proposed, I have `nestingLevel + 1`, not `++nestingLevel`.)  - If this provides the information you require in order to hide things at a given level, please accept the answer. :)

Comment: Wow, such a stupid mistake...thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in your depth and increment it when recursing.

i.e., your function should look like this:

```
var convert = function (data, nestingLevel) {
    var elements = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i in data) {
        var element = createTr();
        if (data[i].type == undefined) { // if is leaf
            element.appendChild('some leaf text node');
        } else if (data[i].type === "folder") {
            element.appendChild('some folder text node');
        }
        elements.appendChild(element);
        if (data[i].type === "folder") {
            var element = createTr(convert(data[i].children, nestingLevel + 1));
            elements.appendChild(element);
        }
    }
    return elements;
};

// and pass in 0 when you are initially calling this function...
convert(structure, 0);
```